# Removing indirect dependencies in NuGet Package

Tags: nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I'm building a NuGet library (.NET standard), and I'm using some other NuGet dependencies.

They have other dependencies that **my** code doesn't need (I don't use the code that use that indirect dependencies).

Is there any way to remove the unused indirect dependencies from my package, so it will be smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those *indirect* (or *transitive*) dependencies won't become part of your NuGet package. NuGet is smart enough to detect that and restore the transitive dependencies on `nuget restore YourPackage`.

You can easily check this when opening your `nupkg` file with a tool like dotPeek - you won't see the transient dependencies inside.

Or let's take [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/): as you can see in [the sources](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj#L84), a bunch of other packages are referenced when targeting .NET Standard 1.3, e. g. `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.
But when looking [inside the package](https://nuget.info/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.1), it's only the Json.NET assembly:
[image]

So you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: But our consumers do consider it. Let's say I'm using dependency A and it uses dependency B. When the consumer restores my package, it also restores A and B. Even if my package doesn't use A's methods/classes that need B. The consumer of my library will have my, A, and B DLLs in his `bin` folder.

Comment: Ah that wasn't clear from your question. No, that's not possible - because how would you as a consumer of A know when and how B is needed or not? Even if you don't see any obvious references, they could be there, e. g. via reflection. You as a consumer don't have that much insights into A to assess this in a reliable manner

Comment: It's an open source project, so I can see it :). I guess there is no way to avoid recompiling A